# Rails: Query with join greater and less than date values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 tables, a `PlayingField` table and `Bookings` table, and I want to write a rails  query that takes in query parameters `Start_date`, `End_date` and `Number_of_players`

Scenario:
I pass in Start_date, End_date and Number_of_players to a method and I want to Get all PlayingFields that are available (not booked) between the dates provided and that the field can accommodate the number of players wanted.

```
PlayingField has_many bookings
Booking belongs_to PlayingField
```

pseudo code:

```
@Fields = PlayingFields.where(bookings.end_date > start_date AND bookings.start_date > end_date AND PlayingFields.capacity >= number_of_players)
```

Can someone please tell me what the best way to do this is on the rails side of things?

How can I query the database through rails to get all available `PlayingFields` between them dates and for the number of players required?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The rails would have to includ the bookings table before the SQL call.

```
PlayingFields.joins(:bookings).where(bookings.end_date > start_date AND bookings.start_date > end_date AND bookings.capacity >= number_of_players)
```

I'm also curious how those two objects programmatically relate. How does a Booking model become associated with a PlayingField ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, to be honest I'm not too concerned about the JS side of it but more what needs to be done on the rails side.

Your code doesn't seem to be taking in to consideration that start_date and end_date are columns in the bookings table.

Thanks